# Find all port forwards from all users

Tags: centos, ssh-tunneling, sshd, openssh

I am running a CentOS 7 machine that only allows ssh access.  On that machine I'm running a number of QEMU virtual machines, each with its display on a different VNC port.  To access a machine I'm asking people to ssh to the machine and forward the port of the desired VNC server, for example, if one of the servers is on :25 they might run

```
ssh -L 5901:localhost:5925 user@host
```

then on their local machine open `vncviewer` to `localhost:1`

Since these VMs are going to be shared among many users, is there a way I can tell, as the administrator of the box, who has port forwarding setup to each VM (or any other arbitrary port for that matter)?

I can see my own by doing `~#` but is there an easy way to see those for the other users?

The only thing I can think of right now is to do something like `netststat -panl | awk '$5 ~ /5925/ {print $7 $8}'` and repeat for each port of interest.  Is there anything more "proper" or succinct?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm still hoping that there is a way to just, say, query `sshd` for the information, I have come up with another work around that will tell me who has port forwarding opened to which ports on localhost:

```
lsof -i -n | awk '/sshd.*->127.0.0.1:/ {n=split($9,a,":"); print $3 " " a[n];}'
```

which will print, for example

```
erenouf 5925
erenouf 5926
```

but only if I have already tried to use those connections, not merely requested that ssh do the forwarding.

This also requires me to know the destination IP, which I do for this scenario (so far, until we add a second machine), so it still isn't completely satisfying yet.